# What is the deal with all the food in the Storage areas in Prison-Architect

Tags: prison-architect

All my Storages are overfull with old food, they dont use it in the Kitchens and they dont dump it automaticly...

[image]

Do i make something wrong with my Kitchens or the Regime? This much food all over the Storage eras seems a bit wired...

[image]

The 2 Times brekfast for the normal guys are needet or i get to much traffic in the gangways. But the Problem with the overstorage was way befor that.

Do someone has a solution for this Problem? I dont want to delete every Item by hand every Day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it's a bug introduced now the shakedown searches all areas of your prison. It's caused because the guards are not careful as to where they put down items after searching them.

A similar thing happens in the workshops, stacks not put back on the benches, but in the kitchen cooked food is not able to be put back on the cookers, so it's taken to storage. The only way to get rid of it is to dump it (unfortunately each item, individually).

Although there is no way to stop it, I have found that avoiding doing shakedowns when food is being cooked minimising it happening.

It's been reported already in the bug tracker (login required): http://bugs.introversion.co.uk/view.php?id=5435